# How to chain Search and Where clauses within the same query with RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb

How to chain **Search** and **Where** clauses within the same query with **RavenDB**?

Are there any good examples?

Answer (score 0):

You just do, see here:
http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/querying/searching

```
IList<User> users = session
    .Query<User, Users_ByHobbies>()
    .Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .Search(x => x.Hobbies, "but also like reading books", boost: 5)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: In this case will it be an AND or an OR the operator linking the where and the search clause?

Comment: I have to put the Where clause AFTER the Search to get the result I want. If I put it before the search, the search clause seems to be ignored. (3.0.3599)

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. Can you send a failing test to the mailing list?